# How to pass parameters from an object in onchange method in <s:select> where objects are stored in an arraylist

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have an `ArrayList` made of Objects.

I am creating a select box using struts 2. I want to use onchange method which will call a function in javascript. How can I pass parameters to that function using values from object? from the `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

A select box can have a key and a value.  Those are the two parameters that you would be able to access from your object.  See http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Event-Handlers-Reference/onChangeExample.htm

Comment: I am using s:select from struts2. Object has multiple set and get parameters. I am able to get parameters from object in listKey and listValue but want to pass other parameters in javascript function.How can I do that?

Comment: @Sejal shah - what will you be doing with the other parameters in your javascript function?  Perhaps you can post some code to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

s:select has an onchange attribute that takes a javascript function

```
<s:select label="Pets"
   name="petIds"
   id="thePetId"
   list="petDao.pets"
   listKey="id"
   listValue="name"
   onchange="someJavascript()"
/>
```

Then just use javascript to get a reference to this select in your onchange function

```
function someJavascript(){
   var mySelect = document.getElementById("thePetId")
   ....other javascript
}
```

If you look at the html source of your rendered jsp, you will see that it just adds an onchange attribute to the html  that is drawn from the execution of the struts tag